# NODEJS how to connect several express.method() via middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have built , using express() , a variety of methods. for simplicity let's I assume I built 2 POST() functions and I want to be able to use them by themselves and also to concatenate them via middleware for combine usage.

```
app.post('/create_obj_1' , function (req,res) {
    //create Object_type_1
    // send Object_type_1 via EXTERNAL API to somewhere
    res.json({{ "statusCode": 200, "message": "OK" }
}
app.post('/create_obj_2' , function (req,res) {
    //create Object_type_2
    // send Object_type_2 via EXTERNAL API to somewhere
    res.json({{ "statusCode": 200, "message": "OK" }
}
```

I want to have a new POST() that can invoke both of the other 2 (but still support stand alone invoking of the original 2
I think it's possible via middleware but I am not sure how - this is how I thought the new POST() should look like -

```
app.post('/create_obj_all' , function (req,res) {
   //I want to invoke the create_obj_1 & create_obj_2 , check all OK, and finish
    res.json({{ "statusCode": 200, "message": "OK" }
}
```

I am not sure how to approach the middleware usage in such case.

On top - how can I connect them to use one each other res? let's say the EXTERNAL API returns some value from obj_1 creation which I want to use in obj_2  post() function..

a Pseudo code of my attempt to use request() inside the middlware_1 -

```
var middle_1 = function (req, res, next) {
        req.middle_1_output  = {
            statusCode : 404,
            message : "fail_1"
        }
        var options = { 
                method: 'PUT', url: `EXTERNAL_API`, headers: 
                { 
                    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    apikey: `KEY`
                }
            };
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);

            // CODE THAT DO SOMETHING AND GET INFORMATION

            // OLD WAY OF res.send here , to allow using in post.POST() was - res.status(200).send(body);

            //res.status(200).send(body);
            req.middle_1_output.statusCode = 200;
            req.middle_1_output.message = "hello world";
        });
     next(); // trigger next middleware
}
```

Comment: You have to call the `next` from within the callback like I have done in my 2nd example. In your case, the next middleware is being called before the `request` is being completed.

Comment: Hey Blaze , I think it starts to work, but I got into a problem about it since I am using 2 request() within my middleware_1 (one after another), so I think calling the next() at the end of the 1st request() , creates a problem for the 2nd request() since I am getting an error of req.middle_1_output.statuscode is 'undefined' when I try to assign it a value at the end of the 2nd request().

Can it be I need to turn my 1st request() within the middleware_1 also into a middleware by itself?

Comment: Update your question, I will answer by editing my last answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the current example, I don't think you can do it unless you tweak the middlewares for the first two routes a bit:

```
var middleware1 = function(req, res, next) {
  //create Object_type_1
  // send Object_type_1 via EXTERNAL API to somewhere

  next(); // calling next() triggers the next middleware
};

var middleware2 = function(req, res, next) {
  //create Object_type_2
  // send Object_type_2 via EXTERNAL API to somewhere

  next(); // calling next() triggers the next middleware
};

/**
 * This middleware is only used to send success response
 */
var response_success = function(req, res) {

    res.json({ "statusCode": 200, "message": "OK" });
}

app.post('/create_obj_1', middleware1, response_success);

app.post('/create_obj_2', middleware2, response_success);

app.post('/create_obj_all', middleware1, middleware2, response_success);
```

**Note** that this is a very simplistic solution that I made from your example. The actual implementation will depend on what input each middleware is expecting and what output they generate. Also unlike here, there may also be different middlewares for sending the response.

**2nd Part** Addressing the second part of your question, if I have got you correctly you want to pass the output from `middleware1` to `middleware2`. You can simply attach the output to the `req` object before calling `next();`. Like so:

```
var middleware1 = function(req, res, next) {

  // do something

  some_external_api_call(function(error, data) {

    if (error) {
      // handle the error yourself or call next(error);
    } else {

      req.middleware1_output = data; // set the output of the external api call into a property of req
      next();
    }
  });
};

var middleware2 = function(req, res, next) {

  // check to see if the middleware1_output has been set 
  // (meaning that the middleware has been called from /create_obj_all )
  if (req.middleware1_output) {

    // do something with the data

  } else {

    // handle scenario when /create_obj_2 is called by itself

  }

  next(); // calling next() triggers the next middleware
};
```

Notice how you have to account for both scenarios where `middleware2` is called from `POST /create_obj_all` or directly from `POST /create_obj_2`.

**3rd Part** You should call `next` from within the callback. See my above example. This is due to the asynchronous/non-blocking nature of javascript.

```
function middleware(req, res, next) {

    // do something

    call_1st_external_api(some_options, function(error, data) {

        // executed after call_1st_external_api completes

        req.output_of_1st_external_api = data; // store the data of this api call for access from next middleware

        next(); // calls the next middleware

        // nothing here will be executed as next has already been called
    });

    // anything here will be executed before call_1st_external_api is completed
    next(); // this will call the next middleware before call_1st_external_api completes
}
```

To handle two external APIs in the same middlewares you have to nest them (or use async or promises):

```
function middleware(req, res, next) {

    // do something

    call_1st_external_api(some_options, function(error1, data1) {

        // executed after call_1st_external_api completes

        req.output_of_1st_external_api = data1; // store the data of this api call for access from next middleware

        // executed after call_2nd_external_api completes

        call_2nd_external_api(some_options, function(error2, data2) {

            req.output_of_2nd_external_api = data2; // store the data of this api call for access from next middleware

            next();
        });

        // anything here will be executed before call_2nd_external_api is completed
    });

    // anything here will be executed before call_1st_external_api is completed
}
```

You have to handle all the errors above like I've shown in the *2nd Part* which I have not shown in the above example for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Hey blaze , thank you very much.
I will be trying asap.

Comment: Sure Blaze , I will.
anyway, I tried this solution but I get an error which I assume due to a miss handle of the res.send in each middleware.
This is the error I get - 
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

The problem , is that :
1. Within each of my my middleware, there is a use of the request() module to invoke the external API.
2. at the end of the request callback function, I have this line for now:
res.status(200).send(body); 

Question is, how should I change it ?  any idea?

Comment: Instead of calling `res.send` from every middleware, call `next`. Make a separate middleware just for calling `res.send` and attach it like I have in the above examples.

Comment: See that my `response_success` middleware in first example handles sending response (`res`).

Comment: Hey Blaze - thank you for your explanations.
I am sorry, but something is not adding up on my end (probably I am missing something) -
Regarding how to transfer data from the request(callback () ) method inside my middleware_1 for example - 
the req.middleware_output_1 is not accessable via the callback since the request.callback invoke is like this - 
request(options, function (error, response, body) {...})
so the "req" is not there to be accessed and updated...

What am I missing?

Comment: I add a pseudo code of it at the question (text too long for comment)

Comment: Hey @BlazeSahlzen , I understand I did not work correctly in this thread, so , I marked this as solved (since you answered the main issue I raised) , and I am opening another thread to focus on my next / related issue.
Thanks a lot :-) !

Comment: Sure, I'll try to give it a look