# Trying to understand how to work properly with : app = Express().method , several requests() in same method and middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

Trying to understand how to work properly with : 
1. Express
2. request
3. middleware

It's a follow up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42341596/nodejs-how-to-connect-several-express-method-via-middleware?noredirect=1#comment71844216_42341596) where the discussion wad fruitful and helpfull (thanks  @BlazeSahlzen , you are great!) but I realize that I tried at one point to put too much issues (although they are all related) into the same question.
So, this one is a focused question... I hope :-)

Case: I want to build POST() that recives parameter via path (/:param1), 
uses it to request() #1 an external API, 
gets the result from the external API,
Uses the result to do somwething and send ANOTHER request() #2 to a 2nd external API,
get's the outcome of the 2nd APi request(),
decide if the POST is statusCode = 200 with message="ok"  or statusCode = something_else and message = "problem"
and res.send() it properly.

for that, here is my pseudo code -

```
var middle_1 = function(req, res, next) {
         param1 = req.params.param1; //trying to access the param1 from the path, not sure it will work in middleware
         req.middle_1_output = {
             statusCode: 404,
             message: "param1"
         }
         var options = {
             method: 'PUT',
             url: `EXTERNAL_API_1`,
             headers: {
                 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                 apikey: `KEY`
             }
         };
         request(options, function(error, response, body) {
             if (error) throw new Error(error);
             // CODE THAT DO SOMETHING AND GET INFORMATION
             req.request_1_output.statusCode = 200;
             req.request_1_output.message = "hello world";
             next(); // not sure what happens here - will it "jump" outside of the middle_1() or go to the next request() down the code??
         });
     var options = {
         method: 'PUT',
         url: `EXTERNAL_API_2`,
         headers: {
             'cache-control': 'no-cache',
             'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
             apikey: `KEY`
         }
     };
     request(options, function(error, response, body) {
         if (error) throw new Error(error);

         //Can I use here the req.request_1_output.message ???
         //How can I use here ALSO some of the EXTERNAL_API_1 outcome????

         // Some more CODE THAT DO SOMETHING AND GET INFORMATION

         req.request_2_output.statusCode = 201;
         req.request_2_output.message = "hello world";
         next(); // not sure what happens here 
     });
 }

 //This middleware is only used to send success response
 var response_success = function(req, res) {
     sum_statusCode = req.request_1_output.statusCode + req.request_2_output.statusCode;
     if (req.request_2_output.message == req.request_1_output.message) {
         meassge = "hello world";
     } else {
         message = "goodbye world!";
     }
     res.json({
         "statusCode": sum_statusCode,
         "message": message
     });
 }

 app.post('/test', middle_1, response_success);
```

1. I am not sure how to connect the different requests (request #1 and request #2) in this case - should they all become middleware? how should I write it? (connect => make them run one only after the other is done.)
2. How can I get also infomation from the request #1 outcome and use it in the request #2 ?
3. look at my code at response_success() -> will this work? can I access like this data from req that originated within the request #1 and request #2?
4. How am I suppose to access inside the response_success() data which is the OUTCOME of the request #1 and request #2?

// EDITED - question #5 and #6 are a late edition of mine but should be a stand alone questions. I leave them here but I will be opening a new thread just for them.

5. Let's say my middle_1 needs to get information as an outcome from the request_1 , calculate something, and move it forward to a middle_2... how do I take the request_1 information into something that can be transffered into a middle_2? I think I am suppose to create a property inside "req" , something like req.middle_1_outcome = DATA , but I am not sure how to "get the DATA" from the request_1 outcome...
6. How do I "monitor and wait" for request_1 to be done before my middle_1 moves forward to calculate things? is there a requestSync() funciton for Synced requests?

Thanks in advance to all the helpers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A given middleware function should call `next()` only once when it is done with all its processing.

A given request handler should only submit one response per request.  Anything more will be considered an error by Express.

> I am not sure how to connect the different requests (request #1 and
>   request #2) in this case - should they all become middleware? how
>   should I write it? (connect => make them run one only after the other
>   is done.)

If your two `request()` calls can run in parallel (the second one does not depend upon the first results), then you can run them both and then monitor when they are both done, collect the results, do what you need to do with the request and then once and only once call `next()`.

If they must be run in sequence (use the results from the first in the second), then you can nest them.

> How can I get also information from the request #1 outcome and use it
>   in the request #2 ?

There are a variety of ways to solve that issue.  If the requests are being run in sequence, then the usual way is to just put request #2 inside the completion callback for request #1 where the results from #1 are known.

> Look at my code at response_success() -> will this work? can I access like this data from req that originated within the request #1 and request #2?

You can't quite do it like that because you can't call `next()` multiple times from the same middleware.

> How am I suppose to access inside the response_success() data which is the OUTCOME of the request #1 and request #2?

If you nest the two operations and run request #2 from inside the completion of 
request #1, then inside the completion for request #2, you can access both results.  There is no need to a completely separate request handler to process the results.  That just makes more complication that is necessary.

---

If you need to serialize your two requests because you want to use the result from the first request in the second request, then you can use this structure where you nest the second request inside the completion of the first one:

```
function middle_1(req, res, next) {
    var param1 = req.params.param1; //trying to access the param1 from the path, not sure it will work in middleware
    var options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: `EXTERNAL_API_1`,
        headers: {
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            apikey: `KEY`
        }
    };
    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) return next(error);
        // CODE THAT DO SOMETHING AND GET INFORMATION
        var options = {
            method: 'PUT',
            url: `EXTERNAL_API_2`,
            headers: {
                'cache-control': 'no-cache',
                'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                apikey: `KEY`
            }
        };
        // this second request is nested inside the completion callback
        // of the first request.  This allows it to use the results from
        // from the first request when sending the second request.
        request(options, function (error2, response2, body2) {
            if (error2) return next(error2);

            // right here, you can access all the results from both requests as
            //    they are all in scope
            // response, body from the first request and
            // response2, body2 from the second request

            // When you are done with all your processing, then you 
            // can send the response here
            res.json(....);
        });
    });
}

app.post('/test', middle_1);
```

Note several things about the structure of this code:

1. To use the results of the first request in the second one, just nest the two.
2. When nesting like this, the results from both requests will be available in the completion callback for request #2 as long as you give the arguments unique names so they don't accidentally hide parent scoped variables of the same name.
3. It does you no good to `throw` from an async callback, since there's no way for your code to ever catch an exception throw from a plain async callback.  The request will likely just sit there forever until it eventually times out if you throw.  You need to actually handle the error.  Since I didn't know what error handling you wanted, I called `next(err)` to at least give you default error handling.
4. I would not suggest using multiple middleware functions that are really just one operation.  You may as well just put the one operation in one request handler function as I've shown.

Comment: @GadiBenAmram - Did this answer your question?

Comment: This is great answer , and I think I almost have everything I need.
I have 2 things I still don't get correctly / not asked properly earlier and I am adding at the QUESTION area since the text is too long (questions 5,6)

Comment: @GadiBenAmram - The procedure here on StackOverflow is that you don't keep adding more things to your question.  You ask a clear question, you get an answer. If you have more questions after that, then you can post a new question.

Comment: sorry - I am still learning how to work in this community.
ok - I will close , mark as solved and open a new one.
Thanks a lot!